# How to obtain a Taylor expansion for this rational function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have the following function:
$$f(x)=\frac{[2a x^2-(a-1)][(a-1)x^2+2]}{(a+1)^2x^2}$$
where $a>1$ is a constant.

I want to prove that the Taylor expansion of $f$ in the neighbourhood of $x=1$ is
$$f(x)\approx 1+4\frac{a-1}{a+1}(x-1).$$
I know how to this by calculating the first derivative of $f$ at $x=1$ and substituting its value into the Taylor series. However, I would like to know if there is another way to solve the problem without using the derivatives. I tried expanding the numerator and denominator of $f$ up to the first order in $(x-1)$, using
$$x^2=[1+(x-1)]^2\approx1+2(x-1)$$
and substituted this into $f$, but then I got a wrong result. Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: laborious but have you considered breaking it into partial fractions and then taking the sum of the individual Taylor expansions? wolfram expands it fully to
$$\frac{2a^2 x^2}{(a+1)^2}-\frac{a^2}{(a+1)^2}-\frac{2ax^2}{(a+1)^2} - \frac{2a}{(a+1)^2x^2} + \frac{2}{(a+1)^2x^2}+\frac{6a}{(a+1)^2} - \frac{1}{(a+1)^2}$$

Comment: @Vaas Wow it works! Thank you!

Comment: then i would suggest that you post your working as an answer to your own question and then accept it, so that this isnt on the question page.. Also no worries